# android onBackPressed not getting called if drawer is empty

Tags: android, methods, overriding, back, android-navigation

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayoutTrack;
RelativeLayout mDrawerLlTrack;
```

I override `onBackPressed` like below

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawerLayoutTrack.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerLlTrack) == false) {
        mDrawerLayoutTrack.openDrawer(mDrawerLlTrack);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

to show drawer if it's not shown; otherwise(if drawer is shown currently) go back.

The above logic works perfect when there is at least one item present in drawer.

But if no item present in drawer and drawer is being shown, and if I press beck then `onBackPressed` doesn't get called. I tested by debugging(putting break points) and putting logs inside the method.

Also no exception or anything in log cat.

So why this is happening?

I don't want to use onKeyDown or any other logic.

Comment: @Blackbelt just go back to previous activity(if drawer is currently being shown)

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your code

mDrawerLayoutTrack.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

then on onBackPressed will be called even when the drawer is open.